# Operaciones con Funciones Agregadas - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen día coders, un gusto en saludarlos.

Tengo este pequeño problema en SQL Server, donde no logro poder dilucidar una solución.

El caso es que tengo una base de datos, donde diariamente se registran operaciones para x producto en venta, al final del día, descargo un reporte (muy lento por cierto), donde me aparece un sumario de los productos vendidos en el día con su cantidad, coste, beneficio, etc.

El caso es que deseo poder realizar dicho reporte más rápido para ser exportando a Power BI, pero, me atasqué en el código por la siguiente razón:

```
WITH CTE_Cantidad AS 
(
SELECT
SUM(CASE
        WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN Cantidad
        WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN -Cantidad END) OVER (Partition BY Coditem, FechaE ORDER BY FechaE) AS [Cantidadd]
FROM temfac
)

SELECT 

DISTINCT
 CAST(FechaE AS DATE)
, CodItem
, Descrip1 AS [Descripción]
, SUM(CASE
        WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN Cantidad
        WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN -Cantidad END) OVER (Partition BY Coditem, FechaE ORDER BY FechaE) AS [Cantidad]

, (CTE_Cantidad.[Cantidadd]*SAITEMFAC.[Precio]) OVER (PARTITION BY Coditem, FechaE) 


FROM

temfac, cte_cantidad
```

El problema radica en la última sentencia `(CTE_Cantidad.[Cantidadd]*SAITEMFAC.[Precio]) OVER (PARTITION BY Coditem, FechaE)` 
donde me veo atascado, porque no logro poder agarrar el dato anterior de Cantidad y multiplicarlo por el precio del producto, pero, que estos sean discriminados por día y código de producto.

¿Hay alguna solución a esto?
Pensaba un Subquery, pero con el CTE no funcionó, por ende, ando sin ideas.

Gracias de antemano.

PD:

El resultado esperado sería algo como:

```
Fecha   Producto  Código   Cantidad Vendida    Total
----------------------------------------------------------
10/07     Carne   0001             2             10
```

Entonces claro, la base de datos está dividida como:

```
----------------------------
10/07/2022 14:00 Carne 0001 1 5
10/07/2022 12:00 Carne 0001 1 5
```

Comment: Algo en tu ejemplo me falla, porque ahi se ve como una sumatoria solamente... podes agregar algo mas de informacion para especificar porque no seria solamene eso? Lo que estas diciendo, parece un group by simple...

Comment: Sí, a ver... La BD me arroja una seríe de transacciones para cada uno de los productos, donde, hay devoluciones como compras, todos en la misma base, ahora, quiero sumarizar todo eso en un solo campo para cada uno de los productos, por eso el PARTITION BY en Cantidad , porque allí resto las devoluciones de las Compras.

Pero ese mismo dato de la Cantidad, lo deseo multiplicar por Precio y que se divida por días, porque los precios varían diariamente y claramente, el coste de los productos también fluctuan entre sí.

Comment: Entonces agrega un ejemplo mejor, con todas las opciones, porque asi como esta, sigue siendo un group by sin necesidad del partition.... usa el boton [edit] y aclara todo eso en la pregunta...

Comment: Por las dudas: Esto `from temfac, cte_cantidad` esta bien? o simplemente no copiaste la clausula `ON`?

Comment: Y adhiero a lo que dice gonzalo, esto pareciera resolverse con un simple group by, necesitas si, relacionar cada operación con el precio de dicho día, y con eso agrupas, las devoluciones simplemente las restas de la suma.